# Transformer size?

Tags: arduino, power-supply, transformer, load

How can I set the size of a transformer for a cooling fan project? The load is 100A, the power supply is 125A, we will take input from 230Ac 60Hz. Incoming two phases and outgoing also two phases but I'm not sure about the last information.

Can anyone help me by showing me how to calculate and chose the right transformer?

Comment: What power rating of the fan will you be using? Also why not use 230V AC fans? A little punctuation and capitalization of letters would help this read more easily and convince folk that you give a damn.

Answer (score 1):

At 12.5 kW, you don't want a transformer between the power supply and the fan.  Even if it is 90% efficient, it's still going to create over 1 kW of heat.  At this power level, go get the right fan that runs directly from the 230 V you have available.